# Physical quantity of energy and it's dimension in the article

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I am reading an article about [Permutation glass](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~mwilliams/documents/PhysRevE.97.012139.pdf) by Mobolaji Williams and not sure about the unit (value/dimension) of energy on Fig.3. If $k_BT_c$  is measured in Joules, then I am not totally sure about the values for $T_c$, ie the temperature is too large.
Any explanations are highly welcomed. 
[image]

Comment: I’d guess electron-volts, but it’s pretty sloppy for the author not to mention the units.

Comment: @G. Smith Well, if it's in ev, then the temperature is about ~1000K. I'm not sure if it is reasonable for a such system or not?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I’m disappointed to see that the referees at PRE didn’t catch this.

Comment: I see. May I ask you a few question about physics offline and how?

Comment: I don’t know anything about permutation glass and almost nothing about solid-state physics. Would it not make sense to simply post more questions?

Comment: I'm struggling for an application on advanced Mahonian distribution in physics for quite long time (for eg. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437438). The statistic can be viewed as labelled permutation graph (for eg. Fig1 in the article) - so I'd like to know about possibility to incorporate it in permutation glass or other areas of physics. Pls see comments and links at http://oeis.org/A008302 for physical applications to have more details you may heard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97698/discussion-between-mikhail-gaichenkov-and-g-smith).